# Widget doesn't change, although new state is called

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget, stateful

I wanted to have a text, that changes every time one of the filter cards is selected/deselected. I made a global variable (I don't know what the best way to do that is but to me it seemed like it should work) and changed the value of it every time one of the filter cards was tapped. The problem is that the text widget, where the value is supposed to be displayed, doesn't change although the output shows, that the set state function worked. For more info see the pictures and code below.

```
    class FilterSelectCard extends StatefulWidget {
  FilterSelectCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.filterCategory,
    required this.filterSvg,
    required this.filterIndex,
    required this.appliedFilters,
  }) : super(key: key);
  List<String> filterCategory;
  List<String> filterSvg;
  int filterIndex;
  ValueNotifier<int> appliedFilters;
  @override
  FilterSelectCardState createState() => FilterSelectCardState();
}

class FilterSelectCardState extends State<FilterSelectCard> {
  Color filterColor = primaryColor;
  Color borderColor = secondaryTextColor;
  Color svgColor = secondaryTextColor;
  bool filterStat = false;
  TextStyle textStyle = unTextStyle;
  ValueNotifier<int> appliedFilters = widget.appliedFilters; 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 12,
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (filterStat == false) {
              filterColor = secondaryTextColor;
              textStyle = selTextStyle;
              borderColor = backgroundColor;
              svgColor = mainTextColor;
              appliedFilters.value += 1;
              print(appliedFilters);
            }
            if (filterStat == true) {
              filterColor = primaryColor;
              textStyle = unTextStyle;
              borderColor = secondaryTextColor;
              svgColor = secondaryTextColor;
              appliedFilters.value -= 1;
              print(appliedFilters);
            }
            if (filterColor == primaryColor) {
              filterStat = false;
            }
            if (filterColor == secondaryTextColor) {
              filterStat = true;
            }
          });
        },
```

and

```
Future<dynamic> filterMealsAndWines(BuildContext context) {
    ValueNotifier<int> appliedFilters = ValueNotifier(0);
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
           children:[Positioned(
                    left: 110,
                    top: 15,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 9,
                      width: 20,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: appliedFilters,
                        builder: (context, appliedFilters, _) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text(
                              appliedFilters.toString(),
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: mainTextColor,
                                  fontSize: 6,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),],
```

[image: Widget]
[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this widget, is the widget you are trying to update when setState() is called, it doesn't work because it is not in same StatefulWidget as the setState() function in result the widget doesn't rebuild.

```
child: Center(
  child: Text(
    appliedFilters.toString(),
    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: mainTextColor,
        fontSize: 6,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

**To solve you should read more about state managment in Flutter, but a temporary solution could be using a [ValueListenableBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ)**

**So you should wrap your Text widget in ValueListenableBuilder and your your value appliedFilters will update the builder whenever it is changed**

```
Future<dynamic> filterMealsAndWines(BuildContext context){
  ValueNotifier<int> appliedFilters = ValueNotifier(0); 

  //Your all previuos code 

  ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
    valueListenable: appliedFilters,
    builder: (context, value, _) {
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          appliedFilters.toString(),
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            textStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: mainTextColor,
              fontSize: 6,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  ),
}

class FilterSelectCardState extends State<FilterSelectCard> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 12,
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            //HERE YOU UPDATE THE VALUE
            widget.appliedFilters.value += 1;
          });
        },
      ),

      //all your other code

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: next time please try to provide as less code as possible, but hopefully you can implement this in your code

Comment: I now wrapped the Center widget with the ValueListenableBuilder and set valueListenable to appliedFilters, and inside the builder I wrote builder: (context, appliedFilters,_){....} and the widget. I still don't have updates of my UI. In the beginning I declared appliedFilters and said it should be ValueNotifier(0)... I updated the code above so that its less and easier to look through...

Comment: Also what resources do you recommend for getting acquainted with state management in flutter?

Comment: @JonasJacobBiermann did you not forget to update the value? By passing it to your FilterSelectCar class and then in you setState function appliedFilters.value += 1?

Comment: @JonasJacobBiermann and for resources, [state managment approaches](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) try to look through it and find the approach you like the most

Comment: if i understand it right Im passing the ValueNotifier appliedFilters from filterMealsAndWines to the FilterSelectCard-Widget... now when I try to make it a local variable I get an error...

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake, you shouldn't initialize it in FilterSelectCardState, just update it  by doing widget.appliedFilters.value += 1

Comment: Thanks this really helped me... I dont know a lot about flutter state management so this will help me get into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that you have to wrap your stack widget inside the modal bottom sheet with a StatefulBuilder widget
example:

```
 StatefulBuilder: (context, setState) {
 return Stack(....) ;
  }
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

upvote if helpful

Comment: I implemented it accordingly but sadly the output is still the same. I don't know why but the solution seems to be right. I updated the code... Could you take another look? maybe the implementation was just wrong.